# Where is org.springframework.cloud.gateway.support.DefaultServerRequest since Hoxton.RELEASE

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud-gateway

We are trying to migrate our **spring-cloud-gateway** but from `Greenwich` to `Hoxton` it seems that those two classes are missing:

```java
org.springframework.cloud.gateway.support.DefaultServerRequest
org.springframework.cloud.gateway.support.CachedBodyOutputMessage
```

Any idea which classes to use in replacement?

We don't find anything on that.

It seems to have disappeared between `2.1.1` and `2.1.2`